# why i can not get the html select option values in php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

i gonna get select option all values(not only selected values) in fact i have two list and the first list is my source and user add their selected values to second list. so i gonna get the second list all values:
my list is here:

```
<form method="post" action="a.php">
    <select name="ap" size="5" style="width:100px;">
       <option>op1</option>
       <option>op2</option>
       <option>op3</option>
       <option>op4</option>
       <option>op5</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

i have researched and find out that we can use the $_POST and $_REQUEST i have used both of them like this but i don't know why i don't get result:
the following code print nothing:

```
  <?php
     echo $_REQUEST['ap'];
  ?>
```

and also using the following code but get no result:

```
<?php
    foreach( $_REQUEST['ap'] as $key=>$val)
    {
        echo $val;
    }
?>
```

but get Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in warning message.

and also trying this but get the warning as same as above;

```
foreach( $_REQUEST['ap'] as $key)
{
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: You have to wait until the form is submitted to get the submit *value* singular. If you want multiple values to be selected then you need to give the `select` element the `multiple` attribute.

Comment: if you are posting too you should use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a value to the  tags, like this:

```
<option value="test">Test</option>
```

Then you can get that in PHP.

Comment: thanks I did it. but the problem is that i just access to the options that have been selected by the user. i want all the options not some of them.

Answer (score 0):

The options need values. The value sget transmitted to the server, the value in the tag gets displayed to the user.
It's distinguished to enable developers to show text to the user, but transmit ids etc.

```
<form method="post" action="a.php">
    <select name="ap" size="5" style="width:100px;">
       <option value="op1">op1</option>
       <option value="op2">op2</option>
       ...
    </select>
<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: is it possible to get all the options without to be selected ( when i use the foreach i just access to the option that have been selected by the user)

Comment: base on my research i should have to change the ap to ap[] and then using the foreach as i using above. but the problem that i mentioned above is that i want all the options not some of them

Answer (score 0):

Forms only ever submit the *selected* options.

You say users can add values to this list somehow.  I assume this uses javascript (though the same principle would apply if you used form submit buttons & PHP).

You need to modify the code that adds values to the list.  As well as populating the *visible* list, you can populate an invisible list which will provide the desired information.

I would try creating hidden inputs, as in `<input type="hidden" name="ap_all[]" value="op1">`.

(I think the `[]` is already mentioned somewhere here - it tells PHP to build `$_POST['ap_all']` from all the values, instead of just using the last one).